# IPMI sensors that have the same name, how to access them individually

Tags: zabbix, ipmi, drac, ipmitool

How can an IPMI "sensor" be directly addressed when the sensor "name" is used more than once by IPMI.

---

In many normal cases, if IPMI is responding with a list of sensors like :

```
:~$ ipmitool -I lanplus -U user -P pass -L user -H 10.10.1.10 sdr elist full | grep -i fan

FAN MOD 1A RPM   | 30h | ok  |  7.1 | 4440 RPM
FAN MOD 2A RPM   | 31h | ok  |  7.1 | 4320 RPM
FAN MOD 1B RPM   | 36h | ok  |  7.1 | 3000 RPM
FAN MOD 2B RPM   | 37h | ok  |  7.1 | 3120 RPM
```

... then you can easily index each sensor like :

```
$ ipmitool ... sdr get "FAN MOD 2A RPM"
Sensor ID              : FAN MOD 2A RPM (0x31)
 Entity ID             : 7.1 (System Board)
 Sensor Type (Threshold)  : Fan (0x04)
 Sensor Reading        : 4320 (+/- 120) RPM
 Status                : ok
 Nominal Reading       : 10080.000
 Normal Minimum        : 16680.000
 Normal Maximum        : 23640.000
 .... etc
```

... and software tools like Zabbix can easily index IPMI sensors via that sensor name.
[image: picture of zabbix happily using ipmi sensor name as an index]

---

But how do you access a sensor in cases where the IPMI has named multiple censors the exact same way?

```
:~$ ipmitool ... sdr elist full | grep -i "Ambient Temp"

Ambient Temp     | 07h | ns  | 10.1 | Disabled
Ambient Temp     | 08h | ns  | 10.2 | Disabled
Ambient Temp     | 0Eh | ok  |  7.1 | 23 degrees C
```

If I try the same sdr get "Ambient Temp" I only get the first censor with that name, how can I access any other censor of the same name?

You can't use:

- sdr get 0x0E
- sdr get 0Eh
- sdr get 14

The censor in question is in "entity 7.1" and you CAN pull all of an entity, but I can't find a way to index "Ambient Temp" in in "entity 7.1." Or how to index any censor by unique ID rather than name.

Yes, I could *| grep* it, but how would software individually index these sensors?